# Redirecting to a page in MasterPage when Authenticaion Fails not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

For my web application I am using Windows Authentication. I have written the following code in the `Session_Start` event of Global.asax page; if the logged in user is valid I am storing those details in session as such

```
Session["UserDetails"] = "XXXX";
```

If the user is not valid then

```
Session["UserDetails"] = null;
```

Then in my MasterPage, I use the following code

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{ 
    if(Session["UserDetails"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("AuthenticationFailure.aspx");
    }
}
```

But, it is not redirecting to that particular failure page. When I check the same condition in each and every aspx page load it seems to be working fine, but the page is not redirected.

What could be going wrong here? How should I redirect to the AuthenticationFailure page in order for it to work?

Comment: Is the code invoked? Is this really the code you are using? Are you assigning your own variables to those of `Response` and `Session` (with initial capital letter)? Are your other pages using the MasterPage correct? Have you tried debugging, and what results did that yield?

Comment: Those are the session variables , i am using and the other pages using master pages are correct. The code is invoked but when it reach that redirect statement..it is not happening

Comment: Is the AuthenticationFailure page also using the MasterPage detailed here? In that case you might have a "redirect overflow".

Comment: AuthenticationFailure.aspx is the page that i am using to display the error message that the user is not authenticated to view the page

Comment: yeah..that page too using the master page and how to avoid that over flow

Comment: Yes, but is AuthenticationFailure using the MasterPage you're describing in your question as its own MasterPage? If it is you are just redirecting over and over again, because it never reaches the page, it just keeps redirecting.

Comment: Perfect..that is what is acutally Happening..how to avoid it..i can not remove master page for that failure page , because , i need all the pages to look similar

Comment: Is there any other way to handle this with out removing master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your AuthenticationFailure page is using the masterpage that redirects if the user is not authenticated, the page will never be displayed, since it will redirect before it reaches the page.

Either handle this in code in your master page, or don't use the master page for your authenticationfailure page.

You can check the path that is requested using the [`Request.FilePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filepath.aspx) variable, and avoid redirection if it's already at the AuthenticationFailure page.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{ 
    const string FailurePage = "AuthenticationFailure.aspx";
    string page = Request.FilePath.Substring(Request.FilePath.LastIndexOf('/'));
    if(Session["UserDetails"] == null && page != FailurePage)
    {
        Response.Redirect(FailurePage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess only way to stop this multiple redirects is by not using Master page for that Failure page..Thanks Patrik for your inputs,thoughts and comments..I am marking this as answer..it is when redirecting to a page with any master page

Comment: You can use the masterpage, just don't redirect if you are at the correct page. I edited the answer.

Comment: Patrick : sorry to interrupt you..i did not understand the content in the link you sent..can you please explain with piece of code..what exactly it is

Comment: There's a remark at the documentation page. *"The Path is the concatenation of the FilePath and the PathInfo trailer. For example, for the URL http://www.contoso.com/virdir/page.html/tail, the Path is /virdir/page.html/tail."* So you can use the variable to check if you're already at the AuthenticationFailure page. If you are, do not redirect to it again.

Comment: So actually, use the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.filepath.aspx variable instead. Just use a substring from the last index of '/' to get the page, and compare that against AuthenticationFailure.aspx